# Intellij module wide error analysis like R# solution wide analysis

Tags: intellij-idea

Does IDEA have module wide error analysis like R#'s solution wide analysis? I'd like to hit F2/Alt-F12 and jump to the next error in my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have compile errors after Build | Make, you can navigate between them via keyboard from the Messages panel (Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down in the default keymap, F4 to move focus to the editor). In the Project View you can switch to the Problems view mode to see the list of files with errors. Note that depending on the compiler the number of reported errors may be limited.

The same is valid for the IDEA Code Inspections (Settings | Errors), you can run a project/module wide analysis via Analyze | Inspect Code and then perform navigation and apply quick fixes to the groups of issues via keyboard.